# Converting NSArray to char** and returning the c array

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I need to convert an NSarray filled with NSStrings and return this c array to the function.

```
-(char**) getArray{
        int count = [a_array count];
        char** array = calloc(count, sizeof(char*));

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
             array[i] = [[a_array objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String];
        }
        return array;     
}
```

I have this code, but when should i free the memory if I'm returning stuff?

Comment: which memory do you want to free? _array_ ?

Comment: in getArray definition you are missing parenthesis (), am i right ?

Comment: Lot many things are not clear here .. what is a_array ? and if you are putting characters in array[i] then you have to allocate memory for each array[i] also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for each string in the array as well.  `strdup()` would work for this.  You also need to add a `NULL` to the end of the array, so you know where it ends:

```
- (char**)getArray
{
    unsigned count = [a_array count];
    char **array = (char **)malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char*));

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
         array[i] = strdup([[a_array objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String]);
    }
    array[count] = NULL;
    return array;     
}
```

To free the array, you can use:

```
- (void)freeArray:(char **)array
{
    if (array != NULL)
    {
        for (unsigned index = 0; array[index] != NULL; index++)
        {
            free(array[index]);
        }
        free(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: getArray function should be changed to -(char**)getArray:(NSArray*)a_array{} to pass in the array name

Answer (score 1):

array you return will be caught in some `char**` identifier in calling environment of getArray() function using that you can `free` the memory which you have allocated using `calloc()` inside getArray() function

```
int main()
{
 char **a=getArray();
 //use  a as your requirement
 free(a);
}
```

Comment: Oh so the freeing is outside of the function. So much time in objective-c that i forget everything in C...TT

Comment: Yeah you can free outside because the outside identifier itself pointing to the same memory on heap which you have allocated using calloc....